# Where are the docs on transaction filtering?

Tags: transactions, proof-of-stake, blocks, consensus, pow

Say we have a user that tries to make a fake transaction. Where are the docs regulating how it is checked before it is fitted into block (pre and post PoS consensus merge )?

Answer (score 1):

Just know there is no need to maintain fake transactions because they don't serve any purpose.

regardless, that is now how the blockchain consensus works.

The process will be like this:

A user starts a transaction.

The node that the user connected will check all the conditions that needed for the transaction.

Once the checks are passed, node will propogate the transaction to the other nodes through gossip protocol.

Later, other nodes will check whether the node is honest while checking the conditions.

And then there will be voting. If the voting is positive, the transaction will join the mem/transaction pool and the miner picks up the transaction and include in the block. Only when the transaction is included in the block the transaction occurs.

In this process, there is no need to store the failed transactions because, every hour, users make countless transactions so it is only waste of storage.

Read this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82194/where-are-pending-newly-submitted-transactions-stored?rq=1) for more insights.

Tell me if it helps!